# Im trying to write a selection sort with ascending and descending options

Tags: java, sorting, selection

I have a selection sort method to sort my objects by there year variable. I got it working to sort in ascending order, I can't seem to get the descending order working. It would be awesome if somebody could look at the code and possibly point me in the right direction

```
public static void sortYears(ArrayList<Movies3> list, int ad){
    int max, min,  i, j;
    Movies3 temp;

    if(ad == 1){
        for (i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++){
            max = i;

            for (j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++){
                if (list.get(max).getYear() > list.get(j).getYear()){
                    max = j;
                }
            }

            temp = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, list.get(max));
            list.set(max, temp);
        }
    }else if(ad == 2){
        for (i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++){
            min = i;

            for (j = i + 1; j > list.size(); j++){
                if (list.get(min).getYear() < list.get(j).getYear()){
                    min = j;
                }
            }

            temp = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, list.get(min));
            list.set(min, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The AD variable is ascending or descending, 1 = ascending and 2 = descending

Comment: In your 2nd if-statement you're using `for(j = i + 1; j > list.size(); j++)` this line alone will evaluate to `false` because j will most likely be lower than the size of the list in most cases and therefore the whole loop won't be executed.

Comment: Why don't you use Comparator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (j = i + 1; j > list.size(); j++){`

The predicate should be `j < list.size();` instead of `>`, otherwise your loop would never iterate as `i+1` always `<=n`, so `j` is always `<=n`

Answer (score 0):

Replace direct comparisons like `list.get(max).getYear() > list.get(j).getYear()` with a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html): `comparator.compare(list.get(max).getYear(), list.get(j).getYear()) > 0`

You can then easily achieve inverted sorting with 
[Comparator.reversed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names and scopes really confusing, a lot of duplicated code.

`for (j = i + 1; j > list.size(); j++)` - this line of code will never be executed in majority of cases.

This s a fix for your descending order:

```
// the same walk as for ASC but reversed comparison
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    candidateIndex = i;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
        if (list.get(candidateIndex).getYear() < list.get(j).getYear()) {
            candidateIndex = j;
        }
    }

    temp = list.get(i);
    list.set(i, list.get(candidateIndex));
    list.set(candidateIndex, temp);
}
```

You definitely need to look at [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some
>   collection of objects. Comparators can be passed to a sort method
>   (such as Collections.sort or Arrays.sort) to allow precise control
>   over the sort order. Comparators can also be used to control the order
>   of certain data structures (such as sorted sets or sorted maps), or to
>   provide an ordering for collections of objects that don't have a
>   natural ordering.
>   The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements S is said
>   to be consistent with equals if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has
>   the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 in S.

I will write a full example using comparators:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    /**
     * Defining comparator for ascending order by default
     */
    public static final Comparator<Movies3> COMPARATOR = (m1, m2) -> m1.getYear() - m2.getYear();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Movies3> movies = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(new Movies3(1990), new Movies3(1995), new Movies3(2000)));

        sortYears(movies, true);
        System.out.println(movies);

        sortYears(movies, false);
        System.out.println(movies);
    }

    public static void sortYears(List<Movies3> list, boolean asc) {
        int candidateIndex; // index of candidate whatever min or max
        Movies3 temp;
        Comparator<Movies3> comparator;

        if (asc) {
            comparator = COMPARATOR;
        } else {
            comparator = COMPARATOR.reversed(); // switch to DESC order
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
            candidateIndex = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if (comparator.compare(list.get(candidateIndex), list.get(j)) > 0) {
                    candidateIndex = j;
                }
            }

            temp = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, list.get(candidateIndex));
            list.set(candidateIndex, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[year 1990, year 1995, year 2000]
[year 2000, year 1995, year 1990]
```

You can also let your class implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to define natural ordering for it and use it instead of `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you that your class **Movies3 must implement the interface Comparable** and **use the sort method of the java class List** and **create a custom Comparator**. I think is the better and more elegant way to do it.

It could be something like this:

For the **Movie3 class**

```
public class Movie3 implements Comparable<Movie3> {


private int year;
    private String author;
    private String genre;
    public Movie3(int year, String author, String genre) {
        super();
        this.year = year;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
    }
    /**
     * @return the year
     */
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    /**
     * @param year the year to set
     */
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    /**
     * @return the author
     */
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    /**
     * @param author the author to set
     */
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    /**
     * @return the genre
     */
    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }
    /**
     * @param genre the genre to set
     */
    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Year: "+this.getYear());
        sb.append("Author: "+this.getAuthor());
        sb.append("Genre: "+this.getGenre());
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public int compareTo(Movie3 m) {
        return Integer.compare(this.year, m.year);
    }

}
```

On the other hand the **Custom comparator** is simply:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MovieYearComparator implements Comparator<Movie3> {
    private boolean reverse;

    public MovieYearComparator(boolean reverse) {
        super();
        this.reverse = reverse;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Movie3 m1, Movie3 m2) 
    {
        if (reverse)
            return m1.getYear() < m2.getYear() ? 1 : m1.getYear() == m2.getYear() ? 0 : -1;
        else
            return m1.getYear() < m2.getYear() ? -1 : m1.getYear() == m2.getYear() ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

And finally the test:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import data.Movie3;
import data.MovieYearComparator;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Movie3> movies = new ArrayList<Movie3>();
        movies.add(new Movie3(1000,"sds","sdf"));
        movies.add(new Movie3(1001,"sds","sdf"));
        movies.add(new Movie3(2001,"sds","sdf"));
        movies.add(new Movie3(2444,"sds","sdf"));
        movies.add(new Movie3(1002,"sds","sdf"));
        movies.add(new Movie3(1003,"sds","sdf"));
        System.out.println(movies.toString());
        boolean reverse = true;
        movies.sort(new MovieYearComparator(!reverse));
        System.out.println(movies.toString());
        movies.sort(new MovieYearComparator(reverse));
        System.out.println(movies.toString());  

    }
}
```

Comment: instead of passing `reverse` flag you can use `Comparator.reverseOrder()`

Comment: Thanks Ruslan. I was looking for something similar at the java class List.